# Hadoop Hive MAX gives multiple results

Tags: hadoop, hive, bigdata, hiveql

I am trying to get a maximum value from a count selecting 2 label srcip and max, but everytime I include srcip I have to use group by srcip at the end and gives me result as the max wasnt even there.

When I write the query like this it gives me the correct max value but I want to select srcip as well.

```
Select max(count1) as maximum 
    from (SELECT srcip,count(srcip) as count1 from data group by srcip)t;
```

But when I do include srcip in the select I get result as there was no max function

```
Select srcip,max(count1) as maximum 
from (SELECT srcip,count(srcip) as count1 from data group by srcip)t 
group by srcip;
```

I would expect from this a single result but I get multiple.

Anyone has any ideas?

Comment: That's a pure SQL problem. Not related to `bigdata`, `hadoop`, `hive` or whatever. It's just that you don't understand the logic beneath SQL. Start writing down what you want, in plain words, and an example w/ a few records + the expected result, and tag it `SQL` -- someone may be patient enough to explain you the basics (hopefully using the newer "analytic functions")

Answer (score 0):

You may do `ORDER BY count DESC` with  `LIMIT 1` to get the scrip with `MAX` of count.

```
SELECT srcip, count(srcip) as count1 
  from data group by srcip
ORDER BY count1 DESC LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

let's consider you have a data like this.

**Table**

[image]

Let's see what happens when you run following query, what happens to data.

Query

```
SELECT srcip,count(srcip) as count1 from data group by srcip
```

**Output: table1**

[image]

Now let's see what happens you run your outer query on above table .

```
Select srcip,max(count1) as maximum from table1 group by srcip
```

**Same Output**

Reason being your query says to select srcip and maximum of count from each group of srcip.  And we have 3 groups, so 3 rows.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The query below returns exact one row having the max count and the associated scrip. This is the query based on the expected result; you would rather look more into sql and earlier comments, then progress to hive analytical queries.

Some people could argue that there is better way to optimize this query for your expected result but this should give you a motivation to look more into Hive  analytical queries.

```
select scrip, count1 as maximum from (select srcip, count(scrip) over (PARTITION by scrip) as count1, row_number() over (ORDER by scrip desc) as row_num from data) q1 having row_num = 1;
```